# SharePoint Online - Search Box Not Searching Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search

Created a Document Library but the search bar does not return any results at all. The library settings (Advanced Settings > Search) were not touched and still have **Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?** as **Yes**. I tried reindexing the document library as well as the entire site. I use enterprise keywords as well as custom columns for the library. Still nothing. Not sure where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: What was the search? Just a simple keyword? "report" or and expression "title:report"? How long did you wait between uploading the files and testing the search? (Search indexing is not real-time.)

Comment: I got some files that only show when I write title:testfile. why doesn't the file show when I only write "testfile"